# .each() over the classes in a DOM object

Tags: jquery, each

I have an object called "contain_questions" in a jquery variable called "con_questions".

As the name suggests, this object contains multiple classes called "questions".

Is it possible to now .each over these classes, or something similar?

I have been playing around with .each() and cant seem to get it.

Any suggestions appreciated...

There are multiple questions in the DOM, and Im only concerned with the .closest() one:
    var con_questions = $(this).closest("div.question").find("div.question_type_bed").first();

Now I want to iterate over all of the classes within this object.
There are multiple classes in this object which I need to .each over, however I am more used to .each()ing over ALL of a particular class on the page, rather than just the classes within some object.

Comment: it's really unclear what you're trying to do..

Comment: I want to echo the answer to each question (which is in an input text field within each class) to the screen

Comment: Please show the code that's not working.

Comment: just create a JSFiddle with your code - that will help significantly

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking to do? You can use $.each to loop over an object or array.

```
$.each(con_questions.contain_questions.questions, function(index,value){
    $("<div />").html(value).appendTo("body");
});
```

Comment: You're assuming quite a lot. :D

Comment: Yea, definitely... but I'm thinking they have never used the $.each method for objects/arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
$($(con_questions).attr("class").split(" ")).each(function () {
    // 'this' will be assigned to each class name
    alert("A class from con_questions: " + this);
});
```

Hope this helps!